# ClassNotFoundException on GAE but not on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created the GAE(1.6.1) (no GWT) project in eclipse(3.7.1) and without having any code added yet, I deploy the project to the GAE. When I access the servlet(which simply print out "Hello World") through the index.html, it is giving 500 error and in the console log, it is complaining of ClassNotFoundException for the only servlet created by the eclipse wizard. I run the project locally and I can access the servlet  fine and see the hello world. Where should I look for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm. I have downloaded GAE 1.6.2, added to eclipse and deployed my project. It is working now. Nothing else is touched.